# OCR with javacv

Tags: java, ocr, javacv

I am making an OCR for my project and stuck on a point, Right now i am performing segmentation on the basis of contours its working fine with few images but there few more where it fails even when the image quality is good, I would appreciate if someone suggest me more accurate way, and if someone provide a code example, here is my current code.

```
public static void imageBinarization(IplImage src, IplImage dst){
    IplImage r, g, b, s;
        r = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        g = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
        b = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

        cvSplit(src, r, g, b, null);

        s = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

        cvAddWeighted(r, 1./3., g, 1./3., 0.0, s);
        cvAddWeighted(s, 2./3., b, 1./3., 0.0, s);
        cvThreshold(s, dst, 100, 100, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
        cvReleaseImage(r);
        cvReleaseImage(g);
        cvReleaseImage(b);
        cvReleaseImage(s);
}
public static void imageSegmentation(String sourcePath, String targetPath){
    cvConvert(t0, mat0);
    cvConvert(t8, mat8);
    cvConvert(t9, mat9);

    IplImage image = cvLoadImage(sourcePath);
    IplImage grayImage = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    //cvSmooth(image, image, CV_BLUR_NO_SCALE, 2);

    //cvSmooth(image, image, CV_BLUR, 9, 9, 2, 2);

    //cvSmooth(image, image, CV_GAUSSIAN, 3);

    imageBinarization(image, grayImage);



    CvMemStorage mem;
    CvSeq contours = new CvSeq();
    CvSeq ptr = new CvSeq();
    mem = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
    CvRect rect = null;
    int px1,px2, py1, py2;

    CvScalar blue = CV_RGB(0, 0, 250);
    int n = 0; int i = 0;
    cvFindContours(grayImage, mem, contours, sizeof(CvContour.class) , CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

    Random rand = new Random();
    for (ptr = contours; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.h_next()) {

        Color randomColor = new Color(rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat(), rand.nextFloat());
        CvScalar color = CV_RGB( randomColor.getRed(), randomColor.getGreen(), randomColor.getBlue());

        rect =  cvBoundingRect(ptr, n);//new CvRect(cvGetSeqElem(c, c.total()));
        px1 = rect.x(); py1 = rect.y(); px2 = (rect.x() + rect.width()); py2 = (rect.y() + rect.height());
        cvRectangle(image, cvPoint(px1, py1), cvPoint(px2, py2), blue, 1, CV_AA, 0);

        //----
        xbox = rect.x(); ybox = rect.y(); wbox = rect.width(); hbox = rect.height();
        img = cvCreateImage(cvSize(wbox, hbox), image.depth(), image.nChannels());
        cvSetImageROI(image, cvRect(xbox, ybox, wbox, hbox));
        cvCopy(image, img);
        cvResetImageROI(image);

        //cvSaveImage(targetPath+i+".jpg", img);
        i++;
        //---
        //cvDrawContours(image, ptr, color, CV_RGB(0,0,0), -1, CV_FILLED, 8, cvPoint(0,0));
    }
    cvSaveImage(targetPath+"mat.jpg", image);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails"? Are the results incorrect, or does your machine crash hard, or something in between?

Comment: the results are incorrect.....

Comment: Have you trying using cvAdaptiveThreshold() instead of cvThreshold()?

Comment: not yet, but i'll try this...

Comment: can you please tell me how to make a classifier that will recognize characters? I've been trying using different things like shape matching template matching, etc. But no hope

Comment: Well, that's a pretty hard problem, and out of the scope for a question on this site I'm afraid... AFAIK the [Tesseract OCR engine](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is the best open source can offer right now

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition#Pre-processing

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some Global Thresholding algorithm such as Otsu. But JavaCV haven't implemented that. So try to find the Otsu threshold level using histogram processing and apply that value to

```
cvThreshold(s, dst, 100, 100, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```