# Find vertex from a object by using vertex detection

Tags: algorithm, opencv, javacv, edge-detection, vertex

I would like to find all vertex (e.g. return x, y positions) for the black object. 
I will use Java and JavaCV to implements. Is there any API or algorithm can help?

Sorry for not enough reputation to post images. I post the link here.

The original image like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/geubs.png

The expected result like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA7uq.png

Comment: -1 for no visible research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you should do (for explanation, see comments with code),

**CODE**

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

// Load the image
String path = "/home/bikz05/Desktop/geubs.png";
Mat original = Highgui.imread(path);
Mat image = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(original, image, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

// Threshold the image
Mat threshold = new Mat();
Imgproc.threshold(image, threshold, 127, 255, 1);

// Find the contours
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Imgproc.findContours(threshold, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

// Get contour index with largest area
double max_area = -1;
int index = 0;
for(int i=0; i< contours.size();i++) {
    if (Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)) > max_area) {
        max_area = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i));
        index = i;
    }   
}

// Approximate the largest contour
MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
MatOfPoint2f oriCurve = new MatOfPoint2f( contours.get(index).toArray() );
Imgproc.approxPolyDP(oriCurve, approxCurve, 6.0, true);

// Draw contour points on the original image
Point [] array = approxCurve.toArray();
for(int i=0; i < array.length;i++) {
    Core.circle(original, array[i], 2, new Scalar(0, 0 ,255), 2);
}
```

**INPUT IMAGE**
[image]

**OUTPUT IMAGE**

[image]

Comment: I am facing a problem that "MatOfPoint cannot be resolved to a type" & "MatOfPoint2f cannot be resolved to a type".

is it caused by different JavaCV version?
I am using JavaCV 0.9 and OpenCV 2.3.1

I imported these API
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_highgui.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_ml.*;

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have used the OpenCV Java bindings, not JavaCV. There, you need to `import` - `org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint` and `org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f`.

Comment: I found that there are two ways to develop OpenCV in Java.
     
The first way is to follow this guide:  
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html
     
The second way is to following this:  
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv 
     
I don't know what is the difference between them. But, currently, I am using the second way. And I haven't API org.opencv.core

Comment: This code will not work with JavaCV, but the idea remains the same. You can follow the steps I mentioned in the code. This post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388683/opencv-javacv-how-to-iterate-over-contours-for-shape-identification will also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I still want to know that which one is better? JavaCV or OpenCV Java bindings.

Comment: I will recommend you to use OpenCV Java bindings. OpenCV Java bindings are used in Android application development. Moreover, I personally prefer them over JavaCV since it is an official release and it is easier to code with OpenCV Java bindings.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let's me try OpenCV Java Bindings later!

Comment: Your method works very well. Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV allows you to take a binary image and carry out contour analysis.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

You could use findContours to find all of the contours (all of the edge points) then simply average them or pick and choose the ones that suit your purpose.

Here is a good example for JavaCV..

[opencv/javacv: How to iterate over contours for shape identification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388683/opencv-javacv-how-to-iterate-over-contours-for-shape-identification)